# Spark UI for Streaming jobs

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

In the Streaming tab of the spark UI, I am looking at the Output Op Id, first colum that comes up after clicking on any microbatch link in the Streaming tab of Spark UI - it has job id numbers 0,1,2,3. Does it mean that all these jobs are running in parallel? Each job id corresponds to a function call in the driver code. Or are they sequential? How can I make out if different functions of the code are running concurrently, from the DAG or the Spark UI?

Comment: If your variables depend on each other, it would have to be sequential execution

Comment: I don't have any common variables except the Kafka stream that gets passed to each of the separate functions in the driver code.